# ion_auth library syntax error, unexpected ','

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

i am using ion auth library in codeigniter when i integrated it and accessing from localhost it showing me error as mentioned in image.
[image]

when i opened the library code line 141 the code is:

```
$user = $this->where($identifier, 'ion_auth'), $identity)->where('active', 1)->users()->row();  //changed to get_user_by_identity from email
```

now my question is the ) symbol after 'ion_auth' is ok or wrong? when i removes this library code works fine.

Comment: this was a serious issue, y this question is voted down? can anyone tell me ? so that i can improve my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue was exist when i downloaded library but later after mentioning here Ben Edmunds has updated code and now the correct code is

```
$user = $this->where($identifier, $identity)->where('active', 1)->users()->row();
```

at line 141 which is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed. Please pull the latest code from github.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, assuming you are the one who modified the library.

```
 $this->where($identifier, 'ion_auth'), $identity)
```

The where method call is terminated by the parenthesis that follows 'ion_auth'.

This would be legal

```
$this->where($identifier, 'ion_auth') ->where('active', 1)->users()->row();
```

Assuming that is what you want.